# React Recursive Child Component with functions

Tags: function, recursion, components

Guys so I'm able to make a **recursive child components** but the **function** from the parent **can't reach** the recursive child (**NavLink.js 73 & 74 onClick**) Line  component. Here's the code I have, I'm using it for a nested navigation for Role Base Access.

**App.js** Parent

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
import Footer from './Footer/Footer';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard/Dashboard';
import SNavigation from './Navigation/Side/SNavigation';
import MNavigation from './Navigation/Top/Mobile/MNavigation';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      checkw:undefined,
      stepNumber: 0,
      currentPage: "Units",
      currentPageChild: null,
      App:[{
          profile: {
            name:"AJ",
            id:1,
            resources: [
            {
              name:"Dashboard"
            },
            {
                name:"Units",
                permissions:[{
                  to:"Create"
                },
                {
                  to:"Read"
                }]
            },
            {
                name:"Lessees",
                permissions:[{
                  to:"Create"
                },
                {
                  to:"Read"
                }]
            },
            {
              name:"Lessors",
              permissions:[{

                to:"Create"
              },
              {
                to:"Read"
              }]
            },
            {
              name:"Invoices",
              permissions:[{

                to:"Create"
              },
              {
                to:"Read"
              }]
            },
            {
              name:"Admin",
              permissions:[{
               to: "System Users",
              },
              {
               to: "Permissions",
              }]
            }]
          }
        }]
    };
  }
  handleClick(currentPage,currentPageChild) {

    this.setState({
        currentPage:currentPage,
        currentPageChild:currentPageChild
    });

    console.log(currentPage);
  }
  handleResize = () => {
      var w = $(window).width();

      if (typeof this.state.checkw === 'undefined'){
        this.setState({
          checkw:w
        });
      }
      
      if (w!==this.state.checkw) {
          if($('[rel="js-rms-page"]').hasClass('rms-page--transform')) {
        $('[rel="js-rms-page"]').removeClass('rms-page--transform');
        $('.hamburger').removeClass('is-active');
      }
      $('[rel="js-rms-page"]').css('min-height', $('html').height()); 
          // do your responsive magic!

         this.setState({
          checkw:w
         });
          
      }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
     this.handleResize();
     window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize',this.handleResize)
  }

  render() {
    const App = this.state.App;
    const current = App[this.state.stepNumber];
    return(
        <div>
          <MNavigation profile={current.profile} />
          <main className="rms bg-dark clearfix">
            <SNavigation profile={current.profile} onClick={(value,currentPageChild) => this.handleClick(value,currentPageChild)} currentPageChild={this.state.currentPageChild} currentPage={this.state.currentPage}  /> {/* sidebar */}
            <div className="rms-page" rel="js-rms-page">
              <div className="scrollable">
                  <Dashboard /> {/* Page display here */}
                  <Footer /> {/* footer */}
              </div>
            </div>
          </main>
        </div>
        );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**SNavigation.js** this is the side navigation that call NavLink.js which basically the `li` link

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './SNavigation.css';
import NavLink from '../../common/NavLink';

class SNavigation extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
     super(props);
  this.props.onClick.bind(this);
 }

 render() {
  const {profile,currentPage,currentPageChild, onClick} = this.props;
  let node = profile.resources.map((resource) => {
    return (
     <NavLink key={resource.name} onClick={() => onClick(resource.name)} haveIcon value={resource.name} dataToggle="collapse" dataParent="#accordionSideNav"  currentPage={currentPage} currentPageChild={currentPageChild} permissions={resource.permissions}/>
    );
  });
  var nameInitialDiv = {
   height:'50px',
   width:'50px'
  };
  return(
     <div className="rms-sidebar scrollable bg-dark">
       <div className="container-fluid" id="accordionSideNav">
       <ul className="nav flex-column">
         <li className="nav-item active py-2">
         <a href="#app" className="nav-link sidebar__link--light d-lg-block d-xl-block d-none">
          <h3 className="brand--font-style" title="rental management system">RMS</h3>
         </a>
         </li>
         <li className="nav-item d-bock d-lg-none d-xl-none">
             <ul className="nav align-items-center py-3 pl-0" style={{fontSize:'1rem'}}>
               <li className="nav-item ml-auto">
                 <a className="nav-link sidebar__link--light pl-1 pb-0 m-auto" href="#app">
                   <div className="m-auto">
                     <div style={nameInitialDiv} className="bg-info rounded-circle text-white d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
                     <p className="m-auto text-white">AD</p>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                 </a>
               </li>
               <li className="nav-item ml-auto">
                 <a className="nav-link sidebar__link--light pl-0 pb-0" href="#app"><i className="fa fa-bell"></i></a>
               </li>
               <li className="nav-item ml-auto">
                 <a className="nav-link sidebar__link--light  pl-0 pb-0" href="#app"><i className="fa fa-user"></i></a>
               </li>
               <li className="nav-item ml-auto">
                 <a className="nav-link sidebar__link--light pl-0 pb-0" href="#app"><i className="fa fa-power-off"></i></a>
               </li>
             </ul>
         </li>
         {node}
       </ul>

       {/*
    <h5 className="sidebar-heading d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center px-3 mt-4 mb-1 text-muted">
         <p data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseQL" className="d-flex cursor--pointer align-items-center text-muted"><i className="fa fa-plus-circle"></i><span className="ml-2">Quick Links</span></p>
       </h5>
       <ul className="nav mb-2 pl-0 collapse" id="collapseQL" data-parent="#collapseQL">
         <li className="nav-item">
           <a className="nav-link sidebar__link--light" href="#app"> Current month
           </a>
         </li>
         <li className="nav-item">
           <a className="nav-link sidebar__link--light" href="#app">
             Last quarter
           </a>
         </li>
         <li className="nav-item">
           <a className="nav-link sidebar__link--light" href="#app">
             Social engagement
           </a>
         </li>
         <li className="nav-item">
           <a className="nav-link sidebar__link--light" href="#app">
             Year-end sale
           </a>
         </li>
       </ul>
       */}
     </div>
   </div>
  );
 }
}

export default SNavigation;
```

**NavLink.js** Recursive Child Component

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min';
import $ from 'jquery';
class NavLink extends Component {
 getIcon(value) {
  switch(value) {
   case "Dashboard":
    return "fa-tachometer";
   break;
   case "Units":
    return "fa-building-o";
   break;
   case "Lessees":
    return "fa-user-circle";
   break;
   case "Lessors":
    return "fa-user-circle";
   break;
   case "Invoices":
    return "fa-calculator";
   break;
   case "Admin":
    return "fa-wrench";
   break;
   case "Create":
    return "fa-plus-square";
   break;
   case "Read":
    return "fa-list";
   break;
   case "Read":
    return "fa-list";
   break;
   case "System Users":
    return "fa-users";
   break;
   case "Permissions":
    return "fa-lock";
   break;
   default:
    return "fa-question-circle";
   break;
  }
 }

 componentShoudUpdate(){
  const {currentPage, value, currentPageChild} = this.props;
  console.log(currentPageChild);
 }
 componentDidUpdate(){
  const {currentPage, value,currentPageChild} = this.props;
  var id = "#collapse"+value;
  if(currentPage==="Dashboard") $(id).collapse('hide');
 }
 
 componentDidMount() {
  const {currentPage, value,currentPageChild} = this.props;
  var id = "#collapse"+value;
  if(value===currentPage) $(id).collapse('show');
 }

 render() {

  const {currentPage, onClick, className, currentPageChild, haveIcon, value, id, dataToggle, dataParent, childName, accordionId, permissions} = this.props;
  
  let childnodes = null;
  let _className = null;
  let _onClick = onClick, _dataTarget = '#collapse'+value;
  if(permissions){
   childnodes = this.props.permissions.map((permission) => {
    let _currentPageChild = permission.to;
    if(value==="Admin")
    return (<NavLink onClick={() => onClick(null,permission.to)} key={permission.to} haveIcon value={permission.to} currentPage={currentPage} currentPageChild={currentPageChild} />);
    return (<NavLink key={permission.to+" "+value} onClick={() => onClick(null,permission.to)} haveIcon currentPage={currentPage} childName={permission.to+" "+value} value={permission.to} currentPageChild={currentPageChild} />);
   });
  }
  _className = className;
  if(_className===undefined){
   _className='nav-link sidebar__link--light' + (permissions ? ' collapsed':'');
  } 
  if(currentPage===value || (currentPageChild+" "+currentPage)===childName){
   _onClick = null;
   _dataTarget = null;
  }
  return (
   <li className={'nav-item' + (currentPage===value || (currentPageChild+" "+currentPage)===childName ? ' active':'')}>
    <button onClick={_onClick} className={"btn btn-link "+_className} data-toggle={dataToggle} data-target={_dataTarget}>
     <i className={'fa ' + (haveIcon ? this.getIcon(value):'')}></i> {value} {(currentPage===value ? <span className="sr-only">(current)</span>:'')}
    </button>
    { childnodes ? <ul className={"collapse list-unstyled"} id={"collapse"+value} data-parent={dataParent}>{childnodes}</ul> : null }
   </li>
  );
 };
}

export default NavLink;
```

Comment: mixing jquery with react like this makes little sense

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to correct the sequence so the function should work on recursive component child.

So on **SNavigation.js** line #15, I set onClick props to pass the onClick itself comming from the parent **App.js** Line #126. Then on the recursive child component **NavLink.js**
I add a value to pass on the onClick props line #65 also I added a parameter on line #70 and #71 so it can be accessed again recursively and can accept again a parameter :)